# Using SignalR 2.0 - MVC 4 - EF, I want to notify users on other pages while messages generated by Admin

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub

I want to auto update or notify users in real time while Admin generateing new alert messages.

Below is my code solution which is not giving any build error and also calling startup and hub methods in when page loading first time. But, I want when Admin add new message using NewMessage page then it should update MyHomePage automatically in real time and which is not working.

I have table Myalerts and also I have enabled broker of my database by ENABLE_BROKER.

Below is my code in solution -

**HomeControler code -**

```
 public ActionResult MyAlerts()
    {
        var AlertsNMessages = AlertsMessagesList();
        var ajaxGridFactory = new AjaxGridFactory();
        var grid = ajaxGridFactory.CreateAjaxGrid(AlertsNMessages, 1, false);

        return PartialView("MyAlerts", grid);
    }

    void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
        {
            AlertsMessagesHub messageHub = new AlertsMessagesHub();
            messageHub.Send();
        }
    }



public IQueryable<SiteAlert> AlertsMessagesList()
        {
            var model = GetCustomerAccessListData();
            var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString);
            SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency();

            dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed) connection.Open();
           SqlDependency.Start(connection.ConnectionString);
           return db.MyAlerts.OrderByDescending(o => o.AlertId).AsQueryable();
   }
```

**My Home Page -** 
**JavaScript --**

```
   $(function () {
            debugger;
            // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
            var notifications = $.connection.alertsMessagesHub;

            //debugger;
            // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
            notifications.client.updateMessages = function () {
                getAllMessages()
            };

            // Start the connection.
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                notifications.server.send();
            }).fail(function (e) {
                alert(e);
            });
        });


        function getAllMessages() {
            debugger;
            var tbl = $('#DivMyMessages');
            $.ajax({
                url: '/home/MyAlerts',
                contentType: 'application/html ; charset:utf-8',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'html'
            }).success(function (result) {
                tbl.empty().append(result);
            }).error(function () {

            });
        }
    </script>
```

**Html code -**

```
  <div id="DivMyMessages">
                @{Html.RenderAction("MyMessages");}
     </div>
```

**My Partial view which is using Grid.MVC.AJAX**

```
sing GridMvc.Html
@model Grid.Mvc.Ajax.GridExtensions.AjaxGrid<DashboardSite.Models.MyAlerts>

@Html.Grid(Model.GridItems).Named("MyAlerts").Columns(columns =>
           {
               columns.Add(o => o.AlertType)
                .SetWidth(3)
                .Encoded(false)
                .Sanitized(false)
                .Titled("")
               columns.Add(a => a.StartTime).SetWidth(150)
                .SetWidth(10)
                .Encoded(false)
                .Sanitized(false)
                .Titled("Start Date")
                .Sortable(false)
              columns.Add(a => a.Title).SetWidth(150)
               .SetWidth(175)
                .Encoded(false)
                .Sanitized(false)
                .Titled("Title")
                .Sortable(false)
           }).WithPaging(5, 10, "MyAlerts")
```

The NewMessage I am using to add new meesages and that is through AdminController methd.

Now, my SignalR starting properly in first load but I want when new message added then it should refresh myhomepage grid automatically using sql dependency.

I have also added SqlDependency.start(connectionstring) in global.asax

Answer (score 0):

**Problem in your Code:**

Do not create hubs by your self.

The following part is WRONG:

```
AlertsMessagesHub messageHub = new AlertsMessagesHub();
messageHub.Send();
```

**Solution:**

You need to get the hubcontext with.

```
GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<[HubName]>(). …
```

On this context you can call the methodes of your hub.

**Detailed information:**

Details from asp.net site (http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#callfromoutsidehub):

Section: "Hub object lifetime"

> You don't instantiate the Hub class or call its methods from your own
>   code on the server; all that is done for you by the SignalR Hubs
>   pipeline. SignalR creates a new instance of your Hub class each time
>   it needs to handle a Hub operation such as when a client connects,
>   disconnects, or makes a method call to the server.

(Go to the source of this text for further information)

Stockticker sample from this page:

```
public class StockTicker
{
    // Singleton instance
    private readonly static Lazy<StockTicker> _instance = new Lazy<StockTicker>(
        () => new StockTicker(GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<StockTickerHub>()));

    private IHubContext _context;

    private StockTicker(IHubContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // This method is invoked by a Timer object.
    private void UpdateStockPrices(object state)
    {
        foreach (var stock in _stocks.Values)
        {
            if (TryUpdateStockPrice(stock))
            {
                _context.Clients.All.updateStockPrice(stock);
            }
        }
    }
```